# vba - change value of cell based on number format

Tags: mysql, vba, excel

I have a bunch of dates that I need to upload into mySQL, and their values need to be in the `YYYY-MM-DD` format.  The dates in Excel however have a literal cell value of `MM/DD/YYYY`.  I can use `numberFormat` to change the way they **look**, but I don't know how to change the literal value of the cell to `YYYY-MM-DD` so it will upload correctly into mySQL.

E.g. -

Excel's cell value is 11/23/2009

I can use `activecell.numberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"` to change that to `2009-11-23`, but the value in the cell is still `11/23/2009`, so the mySQL upload fails.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the cells you wish to process and run:

```
Sub FixDate()
    Dim r As Range, v as String

    For Each r In Selection
        With r
            .NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
            v = .Text
            .Clear
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = v
        End With
    Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Activecell.Text` instead of `Activecell.value`

or  `Format(activecell.value, "yyyy-mm-dd")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this link if you dont want to make the change in a macro https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Format-a-date-the-way-you-want-8e10019e-d5d8-47a1-ba95-db95123d273e

You can create a custom date format and make it default for those cells.
Though, I would say Sobigen has a better answer for your purposes.